# How to filter data at firestore (firebase) and get the filtered data? How to use "equal to" with db collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
export const getSprintByProjectId = (key) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log(key);
  try {
    dispatch(loaderOn());
    const result = await db
      .collection("sprints")
      .orderByChild("projectId")
      .equalTo(key);
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(errorOn());
  } finally {
    dispatch(loaderOff());
  }
};
```

here is the structure of my firestore [image]

trying to get the data by ID

Answer (score 2):

Your JS code looks like you're trying to use Realtime Database query methods on Firestore. I'd expect it to look more like:

```
export const getSprintByProjectId = (key) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log(key);
  try {
    dispatch(loaderOn());
    const result = await db
      .collection("sprints")
      .where("projectId", "==", key)
      .get();
    console.log(result.docs.map(d => d.data());
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(errorOn());
  } finally {
    dispatch(loaderOff());
  }
};
```

Comment: how can I get the answer? Like this     const answer = result.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
    }));

Comment: Edited, sorry I left off that bit :)